# How do I Interrupt a long query in the mysql command line tool without quitting mysql?

Tags: mysql, command-line

While debugging SQL statements, if I accidentally execute a query in using the mysql command line  that outputs at lot of results (even if the query itself executes in reasonable time), the only way I know of to stop the endless stream of output is CTRL-C.

Unfortunately this puts me back in the shell, forcing me to login and select the database again.

To avoid this I've started running mysql with the *--sigint-ignore* option so that CTRL-C is ignored.

Now I'd like a way to interrupt the output of those long queries.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will do this?

Comment: Press CTRL+C and keep on processng CTRL.
Query was killed for me....:)
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @ManishVerma, What? How is that even supposed to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `--pager` to have your output passed to a pager such as `less` which will give you control over the output.  Not just killing it, but also paging, searching and even storing the output better than your terminal window gives you.

There's also the `--safe-updates` or `-U` switch aka `--i-am-a-dummy` which protects you from clauseless `update`s and `delete`s and also auto limits selects to 1000 (modifyable with select_limit).

All of this can be set by default in `~/.my.cnf`.

```
[mysql]
pager
safe-updates
```

Answer (score 21):

Not a keyboard shortcut.

The only choice is to open another session, use [SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) and then [KILL QUERY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/kill.html) the one you want to terminate.

You can also use the `mysqladmin` command-line tool to issue these commands.

Either way, it requires you to login.   So it's not much of an advantage over just hitting Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 12):

From the current mysql docs:

> As of MySQL 5.1.10, typing Control-C
>   causes mysql to attempt to kill the
>   current statement. If this cannot be
>   done, or Control-C is typed again
>   before the statement is killed, mysql
>   exits. Previously, Control-C caused
>   mysql to exit in all cases.

Since I was using version 5.0.67 seems that updating mysql would be the best fix. However I have accepted Schwern's answer because it was quick to implement and works like a dream.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late, but maybe my answer will help someone.

A way to kill a specific mysql query through the command line would be:

1. Run `mysqladmin processlist`and find the process id of the query by the command
2. Run `mysqladmin kill <query_id>`.

   Assuming a query ID 123456789 you'd just need to run: `mysqladmin kill 123456789`

Answer (score 4):

Use `mysql --sigint-ignore`

and to clear a line, use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: This question isn't about clearing a long SQL statement at the prompt, but about aborting an SQL operation that has been executed, that is taking up a lot of time.  That said, Ctrl-U is a great shortcut to know in general in the Unix world.

Answer (score 3):

As of MySQL 5.7 (released in 2013), <kbd>^C</kbd> cancels a query in progress and returns you to the `mysql` shell. <kbd>^C</kbd> currently only exits if there is no query running.

> Previously, Control+C in mysql interrupted the current statement if there was one, or exited mysql if not. Now Control+C interrupts the current statement if there was one, or cancels any partial input line otherwise, but does not exit.

[MySQL 5.7 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html)