# How do you clear an unexecuted MySQL query from the command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line

Suppose you're typing a command line query into a MySQL database and you need to cancel out and start over. From a bash shell you could just type ctrl-c and get a new prompt. In MySQL, ctrl-c would exit the client and return you to the shell.

For example, I have a long, complex SELECT statement typed in but I haven't yet hit return. I realize that I don't want to send the command but I want to have the command on-screen so I can use it as a reference. I'd like to bail out without quitting MySQL. Any ideas?

Key point: [the command hasn't yet been executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498344/how-do-i-interupt-a-long-query-in-the-mysql-command-line-tool-without-quitting-m).

Comment: Just as a reference, in mysql 5.7, this has been resolved. You can now do ctrl-c to do exactly this.

Comment: LAMP stack is so old and has such widespread usage. It bewilders me that it takes  that long for them to fix stuff that people would have run into day in and day out.

Comment: @dkniffin: I know this is an old question, but it is still ranked first on a search. Could you add your comment as an answer (it is an answer already) to help the continuing traffic?

Comment: @hat alright, I added it as an answer

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Type `\c`.

When you start up MySQL, you'll likely see this message:

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.
```

The "buffer" that it's referring to is the command/query buffer.

Comment: Just a small point: you have to do this _before_ any semicolon terminator.

Comment: The nice thing is, it doesn't actually _clear_ it; whatever's typed remains visible. (I honestly wouldn't've guessed that from the message, which is why I never tried.)

Comment: In case you're in the middle of typing a string literal and the prompt is '> instead of the usual -> you need to end the string first with a closing quote and only then will \c work.

Answer (score 46):

First type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

Comment: But the OP specified, "I want to have the command on-screen so I can use it as a reference."

Comment: Works as of version 5.5.40-0.

Comment: Doesn't work with 5.6.28 @Ubuntu. Beside that this is a sequence to kill current screen window.

Comment: Well, you can always set this sequence as a shortcut for this and that. It's the default sequence in emacs and bash.

Comment: Note that this assumes you've got the default Emacs-like readline library. For users who've set readline to use vim-like mappings, this won't work. (Also note that the keys might be different for Mac users, and, of course, Windows users lack the configurability of readline.)

Comment: Does, of course, not work for my most common use case: I forgot the semicolon, pressed enter and instead of cluttering my history with an unnecessry two-liner, I'd rather rewrite the command correctly.

Answer (score 23):

Use one of the following shortcuts to delete the current line:

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to delete everything from the cursor back to the line start
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> to delete everything from the cursor to the end of the line

Otherwise as already indicated type <kbd>\c</kbd> at the end of the current line (a shortcut for the `clear` command) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 5.7, this has been resolved. You can now do `ctrl-c` to exit the SQL command line.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a long command I usually arrow to the beginning of the command and add gibberish, so it won't execute, but I can up-arrow and gain access without having to re-type it. Otherwise if you want to not execute it, just hit the up-arrow and it should scroll you through your command history. Find a short command, backspace, then type whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your shell's key bindings.  You could press home or what ever key sequence you use to get back to the start, prefix your query with X or what ever to make it syntactically invalid, hit enter and you're good

Answer (score 0):

If you came here hoping to find the same answer in Transact-SQL, type `RESET`